# Free Ubuntu course Videos and Book

Tags: discussion

I am writing for help on any feedback about 2 small projects I am working on. The first is a group of video tutorials I will be making about Ubuntu and anything related to it. From installation and configuration to wine and virtualbox. From bash and scripts to videos, sound and multimedia tutorials and from office suites to servers.

Basically anything you guys would want in an effort to provide better support for end users and beginners alike. This videos will be made according to what the end user would need but has had problems learning of finding information about it on the web.

The other is a book I have written a long long time ago in a far away galaxy in http://luisviloria.com/ubuntu-for-end-users/
I would like feedback about new content, update the current one and anything in between. The new revision of the book will focus itself on 14.04+ and with your help can be a great source of information.

I have also added this information to the Ubuntu Discourse at http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/free-ubuntu-course-videos-and-book/1816 where I will also be gathering any feedback provided.

Any feedback will be welcomed. Thanks again I wish

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well this really fits on meta, but responding on best intentions and all that:

You might want to include a troubleshooting common installation problems.  The ones that come up on site ALL THE TIME.

Think: black screen on boot, uefi install, etc